# file-extension does not show in file name when export file to iCloud Drive through UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, icloud, uiactivityviewcontroller, file-extension, file-type

I am using UIActivityViewController to export RTF files in my app to iCloud Drive with the help of iOS11's new File App feature.

The relevant code looks like this:

```
struct MyFileObj {
    var name: String = "file10"
    var rtfString: String
    var rtfURL: URL {
    return folderURL.appendingPathComponent(name).appendingPathExtension("rtf")
}
...
...
...
func exportToRTFURL() -> URL? {
    let data = rtfString.data(using: .utf8)!

    do {
      try data.write(to: rtfURL)
    } catch {
      return nil
    }     
    return rtfURL
}
```

}

```
Class MYVC: {
...
...
...
func presentShareUI(_ shareUrls: [URL], sender: Any?) {
    let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareUrls, applicationActivities: nil)
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = [.right, .left]
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sourceView
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: sourceView.frame.width/2, y: sourceView.frame.height / 2, width: 0, height: 0)
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)

    present(vc, animated: true) {
        self.selectBtn.isEnabled = true
        self.fileActionBarBtnItems.forEach { $0.isEnabled = true }
    }

}
```

}

when doing export job, the code looks like this:

```
let myFileObjc = MyFileObj()
let shareURLs = [myFileObjc.exportToRTFURL()!]
self.presentShareUI(shareURLs, sender: nil)
```

so far everything works fine, both the file name and its extension ".rtf" shown on the UI:

[image]
[image]

However, when I actually add it to iCloud Drive, the extension of file type "rtf" disappeared:

[image]

The more strange behavior of my code is that when I tap use AirDrop to share, the file will appears in the Download Folder of my MBP with the wanted ".rtf" file extension.

[image]

How should I make the same file extension ".rtf" appears also when I export my file to iCloud Drive?

Any help will be appreciate, thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the client program is configured to hide extensions when showing the contents of your iCloud drive?

Comment: @RolandWeber: client program, you mean the Finder? I did notice that in the iCloud drive folder of Finder, the "Hide extension" is checked. I think I can put my question this way - is there any way to put it unchecked (some thing like to set some parameter of the exported ULR) when export the file from my App?
![](https://ppt.cc/fen27x@.png)

Comment: I don't know the Apple terminology. But since you found that setting on a directory, it is unlikely that you can change it on the file.